# getopt_long `--' options does not work for switch statement

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt-long

I have this c program which use `getopt_long` to parse `-` and `--` options, but when i parse `--` options the optarg does not work for the program. how can i assing the `optarg` value for the varibale if `--` is parsed for the program.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>


#include "file_handle.c"
//#include "songs.c"
#include "getoptions.c"

//Mix_Music *music = NULL;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  //init();

  int f = 0;
  int d = 0;
  char *file = NULL;
  char *directory = NULL;



  const struct option long_options[] = {
      /*
        {"verbose",no_argument,&verbose_flag,1}
      */
      {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},
      {"file", required_argument, &f, 'f'},
      {"directory", required_argument, &d, 'd'},
      {0, 0, 0, 0}
  };

  int opt;

  if (argc <= 1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "No arguments provided!\nTry 'cplay --help' for more information.\n");
  }
  else
  {
    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "d:f:h", long_options, NULL)) != -1)
    {
      printf("optarg %s\n",optarg);
      switch(opt){
        case 'h':
          //print_help();
          break;
        case 'f':
          puts("test f");
          file = optarg;
          break;
        case 'd':
        
          directory = optarg;
          break;
       default:
          break;

      }
    }
  }


  if(f && d){
    printf("OPTION -f, --file and -d, --directory are given\n");
    printf("%s\n",directory);
    int valid = 0;
    char response;

    while(!valid)
    {
      printf("Enter one option [f\\d]: ");
      scanf(" %c",&response);

      if(response == 'd' || response == 'f'){
        valid = 1;
      }
      else
        printf("Wrong Input given press f for single file and d for directory option\n");
    }   

   
  }
  printf("%d\n %d",f,d);
 
  
   
}
```

Comment: yep it parses. but when  i parse `--` the optarg does not save the argument for the variables

Comment: devMe, `file = optarg;` and `directory = optarg;` are questionable.   Is not `optarg` changed after each `getopt_long_only()` call?  Perhaps copy the string and not the pointer?  That later `printf("%s\n",directory);` is a risk.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica *`file = optarg;` and `directory = optarg;` are questionable*  I think `file = optarg;` and similar might be fine.  I *think* offhand that `optarg` points to the actual string in `argv`, so as long as the `argv` values passed to `getopt_long()` aren't modified, the pointer value copied from the value of `optarg` for that iteration is valid as it will still refer to something in `argv` even after `optarg` is assigned a new value for the next iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re: *"the switch statement is only checking for the -h or -d or -f options."*

---

From the GNU manual:

> **When getopt_long encounters a long option, it takes actions based on
> the flag and val fields of the definition of that option.** The option
> name may be abbreviated as long as the abbreviation is unique.
>
> If flag is a null pointer, then getopt_long returns the contents of
> val to indicate which option it found.

If `flag` (The third member of the `struct option`) is `NULL`, then `getopt_long` returns the contents of `val` (the fourth member of `struct option`) to indicate which option it found.

So if the long option was `--help`, and the corresponding `val` member was assigned `h`, then `getopt_long` would return `h`.

---

Some remarks:

1. Typically, this condition:

```
if(f && d)
```

shouldn't be reached. Keep flags and  check if the `f` flag is already given before assigning `true` to the `d` flag.

```
bool f_flag = false;
bool d_flag = false;
```

Then check for the `f_flag`:

```
...
case 'd':
      if (f_flag) {
          /* Both file and directory flags are 
          *  present. Print usage message and exit.
          */
      } else {
           strcpy (directory, optarg);
           break;
      }
```

---

2. Given two pointers `p` and `q`, the statement:

```
p = q;
```

doesn't copy the contents of the memory pointed to by `q` to the contents of the memory pointed to by `p`. It copies the pointer values, such that both `p` and `q` now point to the same memory, and any change to the memory via `p` is reflected when `q` is used.

So, given:

```
file = optarg;
```

and

```
directory = optarg;
```

these statements copies the pointer values, not the pointed to memory. This could be a problem if a subsequent operation modified `argv`, because it would change the memory pointed to by `optarg` and `file` / `directory` too.

Instead, copy the memory to the pointers with `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy (file, optarg);
strcpy (directory, optarg);
```

Comment: I need to copy the optarg value when the user pass `--file` or `--directory` but when the `--`  option is used the optarg doesn't copy the values because the switch statement is only checking for the `-h` or `-d` or `-f` options. how can i copy the optarg if the long options are parsed?.

Comment: so removing the flag and setting it to `0` fixed the issue. but what is the purpose of the flag?.

Comment: *"If flag is not a null pointer, it should be the address of an int variable which is the flag for this option. The value in val is the value to store in the flag to indicate that the option was seen"*

Comment: so why does setting flag doesn't return the value?.

Comment: It's used for a different purpose. See the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html